# Java AI find solution for NxN Puzzle

Tags: java, memory-leaks, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

First of all there is a lot of code because i really don't know where my issue is, I do apologise!

I'm making a program that solves a varying size puzzle for eg  (3x3 with 0-8) The zero represents a blank tile the objective is to move the the blank tile around until the goal state is reached. At the moment I am using Depth First Search to solve the puzzle. Netbeans returns a 'OutOfMemory' error when i run the program however if I change the goal state so it only requires one move to complete it displays the solution. Below is my code, I've only added some of the classes because I don't want this post being ridiculously long. Please let me know if you require the other classes

**EDIT: Inserted wrong code for board class**

**Depth First Search Class**

```
package npuzzle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DFSearch {

public static void search(int[][] initial, int[][] goal, int rows, int columns)
{
    Board board = new Board(initial, goal, rows, columns, "");
    Node root = new Node(board);
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

    stack.add(root);

    performSearch(stack, board);
}

 public static void performSearch(Stack<Node> s, Board board)
{
    int searchCount = 1;

    while (!s.isEmpty())
    {
        Node tNode = (Node) s.pop();

        //if not goal state
        if (!tNode.getCurrentState().isGoalState())
        {
            ArrayList<State> tChildren = tNode.getCurrentState().gChildren();

            for (int i = 0; i < tChildren.size(); i++)
            {
                Node newNode = new Node(tNode, tChildren.get(i), tNode.getGCost() + tChildren.get(i).findCost(), 0);

                if(!isRepeatedState(newNode))
                {
                    s.add(newNode);
                }
            }
            searchCount++;
        }
        else
        {                
            tNode.getCurrentState().printState();
            System.exit(0);
            //PRINTING OF DIRECTIONS
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Error! No solution found!");
}

private static boolean isRepeatedState(Node c)
{
    boolean returnVal = false;
    Node checkNode = c;

    while(c.getParent() != null && !returnVal)
    {
        if (c.getParent().getCurrentState().equals(checkNode.getCurrentState()))
        {
            returnVal = true;
        }

        c = c.getParent();
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

}

**Board Class**

```
package npuzzle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board implements State
{
private int PUZZLE_SIZE = 0;
private int outOfPlace = 0;

private int rows;
private int columns;

private int[][] GOAL;

private int[][] currentBoard;

private String directions = "";

public Board(int[][] initial, int[][] goal, int N, int M, String direction)
{
    currentBoard = initial;
    GOAL = goal;

    rows = N;
    columns = M;

    PUZZLE_SIZE = rows*columns;

    directions = direction;

    setOutOfPlace();
}

@Override
public boolean isGoalState() {

    if (Arrays.deepEquals(currentBoard, GOAL))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<State> gChildren() {

    ArrayList<State> children = new ArrayList<State>();
    int[] blanktile = getBlankTile();
    int[] newblanktile = Arrays.copyOf(blanktile, blanktile.length);

    if (blanktile[0] != 0) {
        newblanktile[0]--;
        Swap(newblanktile, blanktile, children, "up");
        newblanktile =  Arrays.copyOf(blanktile, blanktile.length);
    }

    if (blanktile[1] != 0) {
        newblanktile[1]--;
        Swap(newblanktile, blanktile, children, "left");
        newblanktile =  Arrays.copyOf(blanktile, blanktile.length);
    }

    if (blanktile[0] != (this.rows - 1)) {
        newblanktile[0]++;
        Swap(newblanktile, blanktile, children, "down");
        newblanktile =  Arrays.copyOf(blanktile, blanktile.length);
    }

    if (blanktile[1] != (this.columns - 1)) {
        newblanktile[1]++;
        Swap(newblanktile, blanktile, children, "right");
        newblanktile =  Arrays.copyOf(blanktile, blanktile.length);
    }

    return children;
}

@Override
public double findCost() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void printState() {
    System.out.println(directions);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(State s) {

    if (Arrays.deepEquals(currentBoard, ((Board) s).getCurrentBoard()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

private void setOutOfPlace() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = -1;

    do 
    {
        if (j == (columns - 1)) {j = 0; i++;}
        else {j++;}

        if (currentBoard[i][j] != GOAL[i][j])
        {
            outOfPlace++;
        }

    } while (((i+1)*(j+1)) < PUZZLE_SIZE);
}

private int[] getBlankTile()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = -1;

    int[] blanktile = {0,0};

    do 
    {
        if (j == (columns - 1)) {j = 0; i++;}
        else {j++;}

        if (currentBoard[i][j] == 0) {
            blanktile[0] = i;
            blanktile[1] = j;
        }

    } while (((i+1)*(j+1)) < PUZZLE_SIZE);
    return blanktile;
}

public int getOutOfPlace()
{
    return outOfPlace;
}

private int[][] copyBoard(int[][] state)
{
    int[][] returnArray = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i*j < PUZZLE_SIZE; i++, j++)
    {
        returnArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(state[i], state[i].length);
    }
    return returnArray;
}

private void Swap(int[] nbt, int[] bt, ArrayList<State> children, String direction) {

    int[][] cpy = copyBoard(currentBoard);
    int temp = cpy[nbt[0]][nbt[1]];
    cpy[nbt[0]][nbt[1]] = currentBoard[bt[0]][bt[1]];
    cpy[bt[0]][bt[1]] = temp;
    children.add(new Board(cpy, this.getGOAL(), this.getRows(), this.getColumns(), (this.getDirections() + direction + ", ")));
}

 public int getPUZZLE_SIZE() {
    return PUZZLE_SIZE;
}

public int getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public int getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public int[][] getGOAL() {
    return GOAL;
}

public int[][] getCurrentBoard()
{
    return currentBoard;
}

public String getDirections()
{
    return directions;
}
```

}

Comment: If you have this issue with a 3x3 board and running DFS I'd say that you have a problem with you equals method in the board class, if this method does not check out you will make infinite new states. I do not understand your algorithm well enough to determine if your equals method have any faults (more inline comments would help). Try making a very simple comparison of tiles coded by hand instead in your equals method to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: doing some debugging my equals method seems to work perfectly fine. I could be wrong but it seems to be identifying repeated states correctly

Comment: Try making a counter that counts the generation of new states, see how high the counter goes (after having removed duplicated states with the equals method), it should be easy for you to see if it generates more states than the game's maximum state space (total number of unique states).